# How can I deal with my coworker having zero social awareness?

Tags: communication, colleagues, united-states, harassment

My coworker is ruining what's otherwise a great job. I love all my other coworkers and the benefits are great, but this guy is incredibly offensive and rude. Here's some highlights:

- He'll make comments about my body, like saying that he likes that my shirt is low-cut or that I have "nice forearms".
- He tries to start political arguments. Today I was talking to something else in the hallway about dogs and he walked up and said "That reminds me of how I called into a radio show yesterday to argue with this dumb republican. You're not one, are you?"
- He criticizes every thing I do or own if it's not something he's into or owns: "Why do you go to the gym? You know it's bad for you."  "What are your plans this weekend? Why do you like going out for a drink? You seem like an alcoholic."
- He chews while talking and spits food on me all the time. Today it was when I had my headphones on and didn't know he was talking to me.
- He comes into meetings I'm having with someone else about work projects to tell me that he watched some TV show yesterday and it was good.

I've tried telling him that I don't like each of these individual things, but there's always something else he does. If this was outside of work I'd say something like "shut the fuck up" but obviously that's unprofessional here. What are some ways I can deal with this?

Comment: You say 'zero social cues', but when you correct him on something, does he try to change.  Or does he ignore you?

Comment: Seems to me it is time to talk to your boss about it. Keep it factual, describe how it affects you and your performance, and document some situations before you talk.

Comment: This may be nitpicky, but I think you mean he has zero social *grace*. A social cue is something one person gives another (wearing headphones in public) that someone else may miss.

Comment: My politicial opinions are quite opposite of a Republican, but if he asked me literally whether I'm a dumb Republican, the correct answer is "I'm a highly intelligent Republican, but you sound a stupid Democrat". (Parties swapped if you asked me whether I was a dumb Democrat).

Comment: This isn't "zero social cues". This is workplace bullying. He's very aware of the effect he's having on you, take the light as the prime example.

Comment: @BradThomas I wouldn't be so sure. It's very possible that this person is autistic or otherwise has a problem that is making it exceptionally difficult for them to understand the appropriate way to behave in a social setting.

Comment: "`saying that he likes that my shirt is low-cut `" sounds like sexual harassment to me, and grounds for dismissal, especially if repeated in from of witnesses. report it you boss and/or HR.

Comment: I've rolled back your question because it is site policy that OP's are not to deface questions. If you wish to disassociate from this post please see [this Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109044/how-can-i-disassociate-an-account) I know you can do it again but I've flagged for mods who can prevent you from making further changes. If there is another issue contact SE directly via the contact link at the bottom of the page.

Comment: If you want to disassociate only this particular post from your account, see [this Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa-3-0)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like all the above answers have said, yes, you should strictly tell him to stop making personal comments about you, you don't like him interrupting in meetings and when he makes racist comments.

Any sane person will understand and will respect your preferences and opinion. If the behaviour still continues it is a red flag. It's high time you ask your boss to intervene.

Answer (score 39):

Every time he starts talking to you in a way that is offensive, shut him down.

If he makes a comment about your body or clothes: "Please don't comment on my body."

If he starts talking politics: "I would rather not hear political talk at work, so please stop."

If he starts putting down people based on race: "Please don't make racist comments around me."

Don't argue or try to explain your reasoning.  If he says the comment isn't racist or tries to explain why what he said or did wasn't offensive, just walk away.

Annoying comments about TV shows and possessions can be ignored, but when he comments on your body or makes racist comments, that's veering into protected territory.  If he doesn't stop those, you have a responsibility to go to your manager or HR.  (And yes, even if you're a guy, it can still be considered sexual harassment for him to comment on your body.)

**Edit:** Considering the comments about the person possibly being on the spectrum of autism - Someone with autism is perfectly capable of playing by the same behavioral rules as everyone else, they just need those rules more explicitly defined.  So when shutting down inappropriate conversations, you don't need to unkind, but you can still shut them down.

Some conversations are just ones that annoy you, and there you are better off making it about you, not them: "Hey, I'm working with Jose right now, so please can you take your TV conversation elsewhere so I can concentrate?."  "Please, can you eat elsewhere - it bothers me when you eat that closely to me."

Comment: If he's on the spectrum, that could be dangerous, the OP could be on the receiving end of an ADA suit.

Comment: @RichardU Asking a co-worker to not talk about race or your own body - it doesn't matter if they're on the spectrum or not.  There are laws to keep that out of the workplace.  They may need more clear guidance on how to be appropriate, but they still have an obligation to be appropriate.

Comment: @RichardU  In other words, although the ADA laws might protect this co-worker in some ways, the laws also protect me from being subject to sexual and racial harassment.  He doesn't get to be a jerk when it crosses the lines based on other laws.

Comment: It's an ADA-actionable myth that autistic people aren't able to understand that some behavior is off limit.  This is a prime example

Comment: @thursdaysgeek Why are you going right to an accusation of sexual harassment, when the OP didn't even make that claim?  Answers like these is why I am an activist for autism

Comment: @RichardU - comments on clothing and body can go that way quickly.  Shutting it down before it gets that far is best.  And usually the people making comments like that are not autistic, they are normal jerks.  Someone with autism will not normally want to offend, so letting them know that conversation is off limits means they will then stop talking about the OP's body.  A jerk, on the other hand...

Comment: This, but remove the word please. "Don't comment on my body" is much stronger than "Please don't comment on my body" - it is less polite, for sure, but you don't need to be polite when someone crosses a line.

Comment: @RichardU From the original post: "He'll make comments about my body, like saying that he likes that my shirt is low-cut".  That is a clear case of sexual harassment.

Comment: In addition the OP start documenting what he's done and what OP's response was.  That will make it clear if the OP has to go to her boss or HR how inappropriate the coworker has been, and that the OP has taken unsuccessful action to correct the situation.

Comment: @DaveG No, it's not a clear case of sexual harassment.  Why on earth are you salivating over the prospect of ruining someone with a disability?  Are you that upset that we are in the workforce?

Comment: Good edit. @thursdaysgeek  yes, the rules need to be explained in more detail.  The behavior needs to be corrected, but can be done so easily and without involving HR +1 for the edit

Answer (score 18):

Is your coworker autistic?  If so, does HR know?

If so, then you need to tread lightly, as you could get an ADA action against you if you are not careful.

If you tell him to not do a specific thing, and he stops, then does something else similar, then he's doing **EXACTLY** what you are telling him.

Full disclosure, I am autistic and have a similar problem to your coworker, what works and has worked with me is being explicit.

If he's stopped doing the things that you've told him to stop, the best way to address it is to lay out clear guidelines.

> Bob, we've had discussions before, let me be clear this time.  Not only do I want you to stop commenting on my shirts and forearms, I do not want you commenting on my appearance at all.

You can take it a step further.

> Bob, I don't want to hear about your politics, and I don't care to hear any criticisms about anything not work related.

If he does indeed have autism, things that may seem as common sense to you are things that need to be spelled out to him.

When and if you do so, be clear, vehement, concise, and don't get into a debate with him.

If he starts to make an argument, just say.

> Bob, I've already made this clear to you and I am not going to discuss this further.  Stop these behaviors, I don't care if **YOU** see nothing wrong with them, they are bothering **ME** and that is not going to change.  Thank you.

Now, that might sound harsh, but it's what MANY autistics need to hear if you're going to correct behavior.  We tend to think yes/no, black/white with little nuance.  We don't catch subtle hints, we don't catch obvious hints.  Anything less subtle than an airhorn just may escape our notice.  The good thing is that we tend to **NOT** take these seemingly harsh pronouncements as rude.

Good luck

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90922/discussion-on-answer-by-richard-u-how-can-i-deal-with-my-coworker-having-zero-so).