# Informing my boss about nasty remarks about me from a colleague

Tags: colleagues

There is one annoying junior colleague in the office. We are in the same project but on different teams.

For reasons best known to him, he has made a nasty comment about my experience in the industry. He also hijacks my conversations with other colleagues and keeps staring at me whenever I pass by their bay.

I'll be meeting my boss soon. She usually works from remote location and will be soon visiting the office.

I am not sure about my boss's nature. My main intention is to let her know about his nasty behaviour.

I was wondering if I can mention about this junior to her?

Comment: Did you try to talk to this junior first? What you're going to do is much more like a complain, make sure you have enough reasons for one.

Comment: No. He is very rude person.

Comment: Well, is there any reason behind the rudeness? Is he rude to only you or everyone else?

Comment: I think we are missing some story here.  And a question.  I think your question is "can I mention this to my boss"?

Comment: They definitely is the question.

Comment: Seems duplicate of https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/129968/100349

Comment: When he stares at you, is that stare in giving the crook eye or stare in the checking out the female walking. Neither is good, but the answer might differ.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I deal with my coworker having zero social awareness?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/129968/how-can-i-deal-with-my-coworker-having-zero-social-awareness)

Comment: A "nasty comment about my experience" could simply be a legitimate or honestly held opinion that you don't like.  What makes them "nasty" as opposed to just "not something you like" ?  Likewise is "keeps starting at me" just your perception of it or have others commented on this ?  You need more than your opinion to raise this with your boss, and we need more details (IMO) to form an opinion and useful advice.

Comment: i would wonder if you have sought the advice of a colleague about this behaviour, and whether you are reacting correctly to what they are also seeing ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this person seems to have a particular dislike for you and not others, it would probably be best to have a quick chat with them before speaking with your boss. Do this in private.

Give them an opportunity to air any grievances; It's possible you may have done something to upset them.

Once they are finished, explain that there are behaviours that you find offensive and that you want them to change.

Once the discussion is over, immediately make a note of the contents of the discussion.

Even if the meeting doesn't seem to go well, give them an opportunity to change their behaviour. Some people don't react well when confronted, but on reflection realise they are in the wrong.

Don't expect drastic change immediately. If they continue their behaviour, small cues like a raised eyebrow, a frown, or a tilt of the head can remind them of your discussion.

If you don't see improvement, yes, you can raise this with your boss. You can do this at any stage, you do not have to wait for your boss to be in the office.

Answer (score 60):

Before escalating to your boss, you should try to resolve whatever issue you have with your colleague first.  When they make any nasty comment about you or your experience you need to respond immediately with something like:

> Hey X, that comment was nasty and uncalled for.  Please refrain from making such comments about me.

When he attempts to hijack your conversations you can say something like:

> Excuse me X, I am discussing Y with Z at the moment.  If you need to speak with either of us you can do so after we have finished our conversation.

If after directly confronting this colleague they continue to behave rudely, you can then speak with your boss about it.  Try to document as much as possible and, if any of this rudeness is done electronically, save that evidence.

Comment: +1, it's always good to be able to approach management after trying to handle things yourself.

Comment: This is good advice. I had the unfortunate chance to do this when I was left no choice. As an introvert, it's always hard to start these kinds of conversations. For me I found it easy to send a private message asking to "talk in private for a few minutes" and from there it was a lot easier in the setting of a private room.

Answer (score 37):

TLDR: Your manager should not be bothered with this.

What you are describing is, at most, rude behavior.  If I were in the position of your manager, I would be less than sympathetic.

My first question to you would be:

> Have you spoken to him about it?

The next would be

> What steps have you taken to resolve this conflict?

You need to deal with this, or at least attempt to, on a person to person manner.  If you take this to management before having exhausted other methods, it could reflect poorly on you.

Going to your manager now could make you look weak and incompetent, there's a great difference with going to your manager with what you have now.

> For reasons best known to him, he made a nasty comment about my experience in the industry. He also hijacks my conversations with other colleagues, keeps staring at me whenever I pass by their bay.

and something like.

> Tom has been commenting on my experience, and has been disrupting my conversations.  I have spoken to him about his conduct on  The fifth, again on the twelfth and again on the 18th, and his behavior hasn't changed.  Do you have any ideas how I should deal with him, or do you feel you need to get involved at this point?

Before you approach your manager, make sure you've taken steps to address the problem and resolve it.  Do not use management as a means to take revenge on someone's rude behavior, or it could backfire terribly.

Comment: I'm not in HR, but is staring not legally harassment? Are rude, personal comments not harassment? I think this transcends "rude behavior"..

Comment: @Mars No, staring is not harassment. No, one comment is not harassment. Rude, sure, but harassment is *intent* to intimidate. That the OP feels intimidated does not signify intent from the other person.

Comment: @Graham A quick google suggests that it IS (and is also apparently the policy of Netflix that you can't look at someone for more than 5 seconds!), but then again, I'm not a lawyer. I DO recall staring for more than a few seconds explicitly being in a couple of the sexual harassment training videos over the years, but I've worked at a good few companies, so I don't recall which. But I'm not a lawyer!

Comment: @Graham Your definition of harassment is one I would probably use in everyday life, but in an office environment, that is **not** the definition a trained HR representative will use.  In offices, "harassment" can simply be a single comment or action perceived as targeting a "protected group" (e.g. ethnicity, gender, orientation, religion, etc.).

Comment: @Mars if you read the answer in it's entirety, perhaps you will get a better understanding, and your advice, as you are **NOT** a lawyer could weaken any legitimate claim someone has.

Comment: @RichardU I'm not sure what you're implying. My first impression was that this was fairly classic sexual harassment, almost literally out of the videos I've seen. But how does me not being a lawyer affect someone else's legitimate claim? What claim?...

Comment: And as I stated, a 2 second google "is staring harassment" suggests that it is, in the US...

Comment: @Mars and if you just go into management and say "He's staring at me", and the person says, "No I wasn't, I was lost in thought about the project, and just staring into space", what do you think will happen?  Your advice could cripple a legitimate claim of harassment.

Comment: @RichardU Fair enough, although I never suggested OP make a legit claim. A quick talk with the boss, who then teaches the harasser how to function like a normal person ends the conversation, or, despite having been warned by the boss, continues to be inappropriate in which case the case is easier, no?

Comment: @Mars first, you're making assumptions.  If a person has autism, like myself, they are going to stare.  If you slap the label of "harasser" onto someone with a medical condition that causes set, known behaviors, you're going to be in hot water, esp if the condition is one like autism, where the person may not even be aware of what they are doing.  This is why you first address the person, and then go up the chain.

Comment: @Mars So, if for example, this involved you and me, and you went to have a quick talk to the boss about me, where my condition is known, at best you'd be very embarrassed, the boss would CERTAINLY ask you if you were aware of my condition, and then ask why you didn't talk to me.  Then, if I were the type to use my condition to my advantage, I'd be able to bring an action against you.  This is why I said "Do not use management as a means to take revenge on someone's rude behavior, or it could backfire terribly"

Comment: True, the harasser label is too soon maybe. I'd think that the likelihood of it being autism is lower than that of normal harassment, but even if we were to suppose a condition, then would it not be better to have the boss (who is maybe aware of the condition?) speak with the parties involved rather than confront the person directly?

Comment: Why would you be able to bring action against me? Is my ignorance of your condition an actionable offense? I complained about being made to feel uncomfortable, the boss explained the situation, and it ends there. If I continued to take action, despite knowing the cause, then I think that's a different case.... But in the case of ignorance, I either get a decent explanation, or I get the boss to take action against a harasser. Its + for me against the harasser and neutral for me against someone with a condition, unless there is something I'm missing

Comment: I'm not in the US anymore and never was particularly aware of protected categories other than race/gender/religion, so please feel free to fill me in! (PS, I feel that that there should be sort of a template answer for many of the questions, as I know you're quite the advocate for awareness in these situations!) (PPS, congrats on your recent 100k!)

Comment: @Mars in general, it goes like this.  Incident happens, document it.  Speak to the person, document that you did so.  If it happens again, repeat previous steps.  if it happens a third time, repeat steps and escalate, bringing documentation with you.  The reason why you want to be very deliberate is so that you protect yourself as well as eliminate a defense of the other person.  For example, the person staring can't just claim ignorance and that they were just staring off into space if I have two documented times where I told him about it, for example.

Comment: Hmmm... that seems different from my environment in which it wouldn't be considered appropriate to even suggest that a "victim" (whether a true victim or not) should ever have to speak with the "harasser" (whether true harasser or not). But from the cultures I've been in, management is the more neutral option and HR would be more like the tone with which you refer to as management

Comment: I don't exactly intend to become a voice of the people on this site, but if you intend to raise the awareness of treatment for autism (or other conditions), then it would seem more "hard" info would be necessary. It seems to me that whether the procedure is to speak to the offender first or to management first is a cultural and probably legal issue

Comment: Also, maybe better for meta than to mention it to you, but I feel "location" should really be a requirement for both questioners AND answerers! To avoid answers that are culturally or legally inappropriate

Comment: @Mars those would be good points to bring up in Meta.

Answer (score 10):

Reading these answers, I feel like I'm missing something.

Why is it OP's responsibility to speak to an employee on another team about unprofessional behavior? From what angle would OP even approach the subject?

---

This is a behavioral issue in the workplace. My thoughts are that you give the manager a chance to speak from a position of authority to make it clear that the unprofessional behavior will not be tolerated. If OP wanted to escalate things, they could bypass the manager and go straight to HR for a formal complaint and that would be when things get serious.

Telling a junior employee that they aren't in middle school anymore is a job for an authority figure. I'm pretty sure if you report workplace harassment a proper manager or the HR department, they won't (or can't) ask you to go talk to your harasser.

Comment: What you're missing is that managers are there to solve problems you can't solve yourself. If you have not tried to solve it yourself, then you don't know whether you can solve it yourself. It's the same as asking a question of Stack Overflow without having even tried to figure out the answer yourself.

Comment: @jpmc26 Not every problem is meant to be solved by the most direct route. And honestly, I can:t imagine a single scenario here where the direct route doesn't at the very least make things incredibly awkward. Tell me, how, in your head, does it play out favorably for OP to do something themselves?

Comment: Example in my head: "Hey boss, X has been doing Y...I don't feel comfortable confronting them myself, so could you please deal with their unprofessional behavior?" "That is indeed unprofessional. Sure, I will speak to them" *Speaks to offender* "Sorry, I didn't realize I was doing something so careless. I'll be more professional in the future" *Reflects on poor behavior and improves. Offender is then more conscious about the way they interact with everyone*

Comment: And you think involving a manager will *not* make things awkward...? [sf02's suggestions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/131591/16724) are fine, in my opinion. They should minimize the awkwardness to the moment.

Comment: @jpmc26 I personally don't think things will play out as sf02 suggests, and their second suggestion sounds catty to me (it sounds like a response for an interruption, not a hijacking). I think it's more likely to backfire. I feel even more so because of gender relations, but I'm not a woman, so I won't push that point as I don't really know

Comment: To say sf02's answer even suggests how it will play out is mischaracterizing it. If it backfires, that's just more evidence when the OP goes to their superior later (which the answer says to do: "If after directly confronting this colleague they continue to behave rudely, you can then speak with your boss about it."). sf02's wording is just the first step; what comes next depends on how the other person responds.

Comment: @jpmc26 Sounds like a plan of action to use against someone who you don't expect to improve. Sounds like the expected plan of action is severe disciplinary measures. (You don't need documented evidence for a "Hey, knock that crap off")

Comment: Guess it depends on the relationship with the manager...I think a quick talking to from the boss will get the offender to rethink their behavior and hopefully improve things without escalating them or making the offender think differently of the OP/shift the blame onto OP ("who does she think she is? No one else said anything...")

Comment: I believe that even if the conversation is the exact same, the psychology is completely different if it comes from an authority figure vs coworker. Not to mention gender relations can play into it a lot I think, but if OP isn't going putting that info into the post, I won't go that far either

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a good consensus that the first engagement with the rude colleague should come from the OP.

I disagree that it follows from this that the OP should not raise the topic with her manager.

It all depends on how the manager sees themselves and their role in looking after the team.

An increasingly common aspect of management is to be "manager as coach".

The situation is in fact ideal for the OP to approach her manager and say:

> I need some help here. One of my colleagues ...
>
> How should I approach him to resolve this?

This means that

- The OP does not simply run to management to have them fix the problem.
- Provides a record for management should things go downhill
- Provide an opportunity for management to intervene if there is more going on; it might well be the Mr Rude has had other issues that only the manager is aware of.
- Provides a great opportunity to have the manager help you talk about general workplace skills in dealing with colleagues and working together as a team. After you have the conversation with Mr Rude, you can have a follow up chat and explore what you have learnt.
- Depending on the team, there may be a general culture issue (misogyny) that management should be aware of. Specific info on events makes it easier for them to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

> My main intention is to let her know about his nasty behaviour.  I was wondering if I can mention about this junior to her?

The first and most important question to answer in situations like this is "Why?  What goal are you trying to achieve?"

Are you hoping that the person will stop this behavior? And you're thinking that by telling the boss, the boss will tell the other person to stop it?  If so, then that's not the way to do it.  Talking to the boss should not be the first thing you do.  The first thing you should do, as others have said, is to speak directly to the person about the behavior.  Other answers discuss this in more detail.

In situations like this, it's easy to look for a potential action and ask "Is this the right thing to do?"  In fact, the first question should be  "What is it I want to change?"  Once you've answered that, you can say "Given that I want X to happen, is this the right thing to do?"